# Assigning values from checked elements to an Array

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms

I'm attempting to place the values of checked checkboxes into an array so I will be able to use these values to build a custom SQL statement to be run against a database.

Think of it as a Select Query Builder for non-tech people.

I can't seem to place these values into an array though. Any tips would be welcome.

Sample HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="cat">Cat<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="dog">Dog<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="turtle">Turtle<br>
<input type="text" id="demo" hidden>
<input id="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Sample JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        var i;
        var x = $(":checkbox:checked").toArray()
        for (i = 0; I < x.length; i++) {
            $("#demo").append(x.[i] + ", ");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.map()` in jquery. Translate all items in an array or object to new array of items.

```
var x = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").map(function() {
     return this.value;
}).get();
$("#demo").val(x.join(", "));
```

[**Sample jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bt2ezmve/)

Comment: Thanks! You live up to your name.